# Cannot set maximum height of JEditorPane inside JScrollPane inside JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jdialog, jeditorpane

So I want to achieve something very simple.
In my application, users can consult the content of some files.
First of all, the content of the files is in HTML, so I used JEditorPane to display it. Secondly, the file content is a bit long. Since I want it to be scrollable, I wrapped it in a JScrollPane. Lastly, this window should be modal. So I wrapped it again in a JDialog. Here's my code:

```
JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
ep.setContentType("text/html");
ep.setEditable(false);
ep.setText(longHtmlString);
        
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ep);
sp.getViewport().setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 1500));
        
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.getContentPane().add(sp);
dialog.setModal(true);
dialog.setResizable(false);
dialog.pack();

dialog.setVisible(true);
```

But here is the output that I get:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSOlV.png)

As you can see, there is NO scrollbar and the dialog just takes the entire height of the HTML content... I want the dialog to have a fixed height with a vertical scrollbar. The content will ALWAYS be long like on the screenshot. I already tried setting the size on any of the 3 components (editorpane, scrollpane, jdialog) but I cannot achieve what I want. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would go about this a different way - from the inside out. 1) Show a simple HTML having a single `div` of suitable width and height. 2) Pack the GUI. 3) Set the HTML that needs to be displayed. -- If you cannot get that alternate approach to work, post a [mre] of your attempt as an [edit] to the question.

Comment: *As you can see, there is NO scrollbar and the dialog just takes the entire height of the HTML* - well you set the preferred height to be 1500, which is a larger height than most monitors. In any case I would set the preferred size of the scroll pane itself (to a more reasonable value) and not play with the preferred size of any component displayed in the scroll pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dialog is going to be **Modal** so make sure you set the dialog to always be on top of other windows:

```
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
```

Display the dialog realative to something like a specific Window or component. If you want the dialog to display in the center of the monitor screen then make it display relative to `null`:

```
........
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

You can get away with setting the preferred size of things at the final component level in this particular case however you will eventually find later on that this can lead to some undesirable results. Set the dialog to the size you want then let `pack()` take care of the rest:

```
dialog.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 400));
```

Set the dimensions to something more realistic as @camickr has already mentioned in comments. A height setting of `1500` is a little much but I'm sure this was a typo and your actual intention was `500, 500`.

If you are going to have a title bar for you dialog (which most do) then it's always nice to have an actual title in it so as to denote what the display content is about:

```
dialog.setTitle("Would be nice to have a title here... - longHtmlString");
```

Set your Scroll Bar Pane's **horizontal** and **vertical** policies so that the component knows what is expected:

```
sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

With the above setting, either of the scroll bars will be displayed **IF** they are needed.

Sometimes it's just nice to be able to resize a window a little bit to to catch that wee bit of data that went beyond limits instead of working a scroll bar all the time. You might want to consider removing the `dialog.setResizable(false);` line of code so that the dialog can indeed be resized if desired.

So that the text material placed into the JEditorPane starts its display from the top of the document instead of the bottom of the document, you may want to consider moving the caret location to index location `0`. Yes, this will work even if the Editor Pane is set to non-editable:

```
ep.setCaretPosition(0);
```

The following **should** work fine:

```
// The JDialog Window...
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setTitle("Would be nice to have a title here... - longHtmlString");
dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 400));
dialog.setModal(true);
//dialog.setResizable(false);
    
// The JEditorPane...
JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
ep.setContentType("text/html");
ep.setEditable(false);
ep.setText(longHtmlString);
ep.setCaretPosition(0);

// The JScrollPane...
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(ep);     // Declared JEditorPane added here.
sp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

// Add components to dialog, pack it, and display the dialog.
dialog.getContentPane().add(sp);
dialog.pack();
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```